# Select list gives text between option text

Tags: html, forms, laravel, selectlist

I have the following dropdownlist/ selectlist in my form:

```
<select class="form-control" id="properties" name="properties1"><option value"35" disabled>white  (Sold Out)</option><option value"36" disabled>yellow  (Sold Out)</option><option value"37" >blue </option></select>
```

Why is this returning the value between the option tags instead of the value of the options? I need the Id's ofcourse.

I am using Laravel and process this form data with this tag: `Input::get('properties');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the syntax of the HTML is wrong.

You are missing the equals sign between the attribute names and attribute values. The `value"35"` should be `value="35"`.

Comment: maybe I should go to sleep ;)
Thank you very much!